# How can I add the Recycler View Object to favorites in another activity?

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview, favorites

I'm making a note taking app, I need to add recycler view objects
click on the crown from here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXMrG.png

Here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssn9g.png

By clicking on this crown, they should be saved in the "Favorites" activity:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOvyj.png

I searched for information on the Internet, but did not find a suitable one.

How can I implement this?

```
in_fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                in_fav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                from_fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Pressing the crown button to add to favorites
            }
        });

        from_fav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                from_fav.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                in_fav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Pressing the crown button to remove from favorites
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to implement this is by adding isFavorite to your Note class, and then you can show them in your favorites activity where isFavorite is true by fetching them from the database. So, your favorites activity has only the favorite notes.